# Azure Function Service Bus Trigger throws error A host error has occurred during startup operation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus

[image]I am developing a sample application for Azure Function for Service Bus Trigger but Facing the below issue while running it locally.

```
A host error has occurred during startup operation 'c283f2ad-3bf2-4efe-99f9-73cef19ca6ae'.
[08-06-2020 12:29:59] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'Endpoint=sb://ntestsb1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;[Hidden Credential]' is missing or empty
```

Please find below the code.

```
 public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sb-fun-transactional-dev", Connection = "Endpoint=sb://sb-fun-dev.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<accessKeyName>;SharedAccessKey=<accessKey>")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @nirav, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remove the function secrets. You can replace it with placeholders like this: `SharedAccessKeyName=<accessKeyName>;SharedAccessKey=<accessKey>`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't put the connection string in the `Connection` parameter, but the *name* of the *connection string setting* in Azure Function App Configuration.

The error you get states it cannot find the setting with the name `<your-entire-connection-string>`.

Your code would become something like

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sb-fun-transactional-dev", Connection = "sbConnString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

and you would have a setting `sbConnString` under the [Function App Configuration - Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings).

[image: application settings]

Comment: Hi rickvdbosch
I trried the same as mentioned by you in the post but facing the same issue as mentioned below.
"A host error has occurred during startup operation 'd4d615d5-2804-44a8-af2b-423c08871811'.
[09-06-2020 07:30:50] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'sbConnString' is missing or empty"

Can you please help.

Comment: @niravshah did you add the `sbConnString` as a setting under Function App - Configuration - **Connection Strings**? Because it should be under Application Settings. Connection Strings is only for stuff like SQL

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by you I have added it to the application settings for the azure function but still facing the issue.

Comment: Could you update your question with a screenshot of the configuration for your Function?

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: any Idea why am I facing this issue?

Comment: @niravshah, your screenshot shows that you're doing different to what rick says. You should use public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sb-fun-transactional-dev", Connection = "sbConnString". Notice *Connection = "sbConnString"*, it has only "sbConnString", not the complete connection string as you are doing, but the name of the settings key

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

do like this It worked for me.(This is for running Azure function locally)
First add a new key  in Values in local.settings.json file.
Then use that name instead of connection String as displayed in screenshot.